# interface for getting pointer of derived class from another module

Tags: c++, oop

I have given an interface of base class (with all functions declared as virtual) to another module in my project.
Now I can call these functions from pointer type of base class, while its internal implementation would be done by other module in a derived class. I would need to get pointer to its derived class. What is best way for interface of getting this pointer?
Only way I can think is by other module providing an init API which returns pointer to derived class.

Regards,

Comment: Could you post some code or at least a skeleton to clarify your issue?

Answer (score 0):

> What is best way for interface ...

*is a abstract.. your best way* :)

for example you can use IoC-Container's for different injection in your classes:

- [Inversion of Control Containers and the Dependency Injection pattern](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html)

or simple:

```
interface ICGridEventKeys
{
    virtual LRESULT onKeyHandler(UINT /*uMsg*/, WPARAM /*wParam*/, LPARAM /*lParam*/, BOOL& /*bHandled*/) = 0;
};
typedef ICGridEventKeys* ICGridEventKeys_;
```

some logic:

```
class CEditBox
{
public:

    CEditBox(LPCTSTR name, ICGridEventKeys_ evt):
      evt(evt)
    {
        ...
        evt->onKeyHandler(uMsg, wParam, lParam, bHandled);
        ...
    }

protected:
    ICGridEventKeys_ evt;
};
```

implement ICGridEventKeys:

```
class Sample: public ICGridEventKeys
{
public:

    LRESULT onKeyHandler(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, BOOL& bHandled)
    {
        //..
        return 0;
    }

    void m()
    {
        ...
        CEditBox box(_T(""), this);
    }

}
```

full sample you can see with my old wrapper - [CGridItem.h](https://bitbucket.org/3F/sandbox/src/master-C%2B%2B/cpp/ui/grid/CGrid/CGridItem.h)

or something else., please clarify your question